# Android adb am profile enlarged buffer size

Tags: android, buffer, adb, profile, activity-manager

does somebody know how to enlarge the buffer size for the "am profile" command?
Or is it even possible to enlarge the buffer size using command line?

I know it is possible with the Debug.startMethodTracing(), but I need it for the "am profile" command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and had to look into this in details. Turned out there is no option to use with `adb am` to set the buffer size, while `android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing` has that option.

The difference seems to be the way `ActivityManager` and `Debug` do this. `Debug` directly accesses VMDebug and calls the native function `startMethodTracingNative` which accepts buffer size as the parameter, while AM calls a function from ActivityManagerService called profileControl, which uses ApplicationThreadNative to start profiling. This might eventually lead to the same native method VMDebug uses, I don't know, but what's obvious is that there is no buffer parameter considered inside AMS, so not possible to set it via adb.